# Compilation error while using templates

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
template<class U, class W>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream & out, const Alias<U, W> & A)
{
    out<<A.ItoS.size()<<std::endl;
    for (std::map<W, U>::const_iterator it = A.ItoS.begin(); it != A.ItoS.end(); it++)
        out<<it -> first<<" "<<it -> second<<std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

errors are on line :
    `for (std::map<W, U>::const_iterator it = A.ItoS.begin(); it != A.ItoS.end(); it++)`

error: expected ';' before 'it'

error: 'it' was not declared in this scope

Other class functions dont't have any compilation problems.

While I was using std::string instead of U and int instead of W everything was fine.
I am using Codeblocks 10 with MinGW compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `typename` here:

```
  typename std::map<W, U>::const_iterator it = A.ItoS.begin();
//^^^^^^^
```

`const_iterator` is a dependent name, therefore `typename` is required here. For detail explanation, read this topic:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

In C++11, you could simply write:

```
 auto it = A.ItoS.begin();
```

which is a relief to C++ programmers!

Comment: Thank you, I am rather new to C++ so why do I need to put typename there?

Comment: @lpp: Go through the link : [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Now I have aditional  problem using that class. In my simple program consisting of header, class and main program, when I try using that class members or functions I get error : undefined reference to `Alias<std::string, int>::Exist(std::string const&) const'  Before this change from non-template to template everything was working properly. Is there anything what I could have missed ? I defined class as Alias<string, int> Al

Comment: @lpp: That is a different problem. It seems you've defined them in `.cpp` file. If so, then move them into `.h` file, because template definitions should reside in `.h` file itself.

Comment: I don't understand what I have to do. Everything is defined in .hpp file and only implemented in .cpp file. Below are my sources for this.
Main file(.cpp) : http://pastebin.com/WKd3gksU
Header(.hpp) :  http://pastebin.com/yRPjzTyT
Implementation (.cpp) : http://pastebin.com/S9eCbC0s

Comment: @lpp: Move them to `.h` file. The functions of a class template should be implemented in the `.h` file itself, not in `.cpp` file. There should not exist `.cpp` file. Just move all the code to `.h` file.

Comment: I've moved them and all functions work except functions related to stream (overloading operator << and >> ). For them I still have the same error.

Comment: @lpp: that possibly means, you've not overloaded `<<` and `>>` for the types you're working with.

Comment: So I need to explicitly overload every type for operators I work with? I will have to make std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream & out, const Alias<string, int> & A) 
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream & out, const Alias<string, char> & A), etc.

Comment: @lpp: No. In that case, you don't have to. Since in your case, `W` and `U` are types for which there already exist `<<` and `>>`. There must be some other problem.